# What do I need to change in order to put icon syde-by-side

Tags: html, jquery, css

I spend hours and hours to see what I made wrong but whatever I try nothing happened. So the problem is following.
I have two action in my Index page and I put icon (font-awesome libary) to represent Edit and Delete.
And I want to put icon side-by-side, right now there are separate in another row

[image]

What I try so far is to make datatabe smaller but however this doesn't help me.

```
<div class="panel panel-flat">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table datatable-responsive datatable-patients">
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-blue">
                    <th>
                        Firstname
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Lastname
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Contact
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Email
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Blood Group
                    </th>
                    <th></th>     
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr id="tr-id-@item.patient_id">
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.patient_first_name)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.patient_last_name)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.patient_contact_number)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.patient_email)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.patient_blood_group)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <ul class="icons-list text-left">
                                <li class="text-primary-600"><a href="~/Patients/Edit?Id=@item.patient_id"><i class="icon-pencil7"></i></a></li>
                                <li class="text-danger-600"><a class="delete_pacient" href="javascript:;" data-id="@item.patient_id"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                 }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>




 $('.datatable-patients').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',

        columnDefs: [
            {
                responsivePriority: 1,
                targets: -1
            },
            {
                targets: [-1],
                orderable: false,
                searchable: false,
                printable: false,
                width: "120"
            }
        ]
    });
```

I try to add  in separate  but doesn't work as well.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong here ? WHere did I made mistake ?

Comment: `.icons-list li { display: inline; }` set them to an inline element and therefor they will be displayed inline instead of block-level.

Comment: li are block level elements, reset display to inline

Comment: Thank you so much guys. Please post as answer that another user can see also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this CSS:

```
.icons-list{
  display: flex;
  list-style: none; /* To remove the list bullets */
}
.icons-list li{
  margin-left: 1em; /* adjust it */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add: `.icons-list li { display: inline; }` to change them from `Block-Level element` to `Inline element`.

```css
.icons-list li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>List are Block-Level elements. Therefor they will be displayed below each other.</p>
<ul>
  <li>&#x212B;</li>
  <li>&#x2126;</li>
</ul>

<br>

<p>By changing them to an inline element (display: inline;) they will be displayed next to each other.</p>
<ul class="icons-list">
  <li>&#x212B;</li>
  <li>&#x2126;</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `<li>` marker builds a list of elements. I think you should try using a `<div>` instead.

Comment: using a list is not wrong. has something to do with the DOM. There is no reason to switch to divs for that use. You can solve it with just a single CSS-line as 2 comments already stated.

Comment: This is not solution